# Jenkins mercurial cloning a Bitbucket repository with every build

Tags: mercurial, continuous-integration, jenkins

I'm using Jenkins and Bitbucket with the Mercurial plugin on windows. Every time I run a build, it clones my application again with the following message.

```
ERROR: Workspace reports paths.default as
read config from: C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\hgrc.d\Mercurial.rc
read config from: C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\hgrc.d\MergePatterns.rc
read config from: C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\hgrc.d\MergeTools.rc
read config from: C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\hgrc.d\Paths.rc
read config from: C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\mercurial.ini
read config from: C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\.hgrc
read config from: C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\mercurial.ini
read config from: C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\.hgrc
none: https://user:password@bitbucket.org/user/app
which looks different than  https://user:password@bitbucket.org/user/app
so falling back to fresh clone rather than incremental update
```

Does anyone know how to prevent this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you modify Jenkins task to use existing clone and don't remove it after build? I know nothing about Jenkins

Comment: @LazyBadger - neither do I! I installed it yesterday. Still trying to work it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Jekins configuration switch off Mercurial Debug option.

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-13329